# TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 11 were given

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

[error message img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDIUS.jpg)

I have been trying to access a webpage from webdriver and click a specific frame (and it used to work), but now its giving me this positional argument error. Heres the block of code Ive been trying to run:

```
driver.get(mastercon)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
wait(driver, 120).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it('iframe_cbk'))
sleep(40)
```

Error given:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 driver.get(mastercon)
      2 driver.switch_to.default_content()
----> 3 wait(driver, 120).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("iframe_cbk"))
      4 sleep(40)
      6 #driver.switch_to_frame('iframe_cbk')
      7 
      8 #Dashboard/Filter

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:78, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
     76 while True:
     77     try:
---> 78         value = method(self._driver)
     79         if value:
     80             return value

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py:256, in frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it.<locals>._predicate(driver)
    254 try:
    255     if hasattr(locator, '__iter__'):
--> 256         driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(*locator))
    257     else:
    258         driver.switch_to.frame(locator)

TypeError: find_element() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 11 were given
```

Larger code block (this runs when Im already on the homepage of the desired website)

```
# change frame 
do_dispute = []
for tx_dispute,refund_date in zip(df_refund.claim_id,df_refund.refund_date):
    try:
        driver.get(mastercon)
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        wait(driver, 120).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("iframe_cbk"))
        sleep(40)
        
        #driver.switch_to_frame('iframe_cbk')

        #Dashboard/Filter
        sleep(15)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(dashboard_slash_filter_button).click()

        #New Filter
        sleep(15)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(new_filter_button).click()

        # Insert claim_id in text box Claim Manager ID 
        sleep(8)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(text_box_claim_id).send_keys(tx_dispute)

        # Click to search for transaction
        sleep(4)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(search_tx).click()
```

Comment: where's the block of code responsible for the error?

Comment: It seems to be this one on the post, when I try running it on Jupyter it gives me the message. It is supposed to simply wait for a frame to load and click it, then the rest of the code goes on interacting with the frame.

Comment: The error is within a function called find_element(), and there's no such function in the code you provided.

Comment: Added an image of the error on the beginning of the thread, don’t know if this helps you. 

When I try running it with the other blocks that should interact with the frame, it doesn’t give me the error but the page won’t stop reloading,  I got the TypeError when trying to “break” the code and run it step by step, and this specific block mentioned on the thread is the one which gives me the error

Comment: Sorry but a pic still doesn't help, we need to see the code.

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message by **copying and pasting**, starting with the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and formatting it like code.

Comment: Added the full block of interaction, the problem is that before this I only log-in into the website, and this beggining of the code is what gives me the error, I wonder if it is some syntax issue, but Ive been trying to edit it with parenthesis and everything I can but no success yet.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry, added the complete error message

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated syntax.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(dashboard_slash_filter_button).click()
```

should be:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '...').click()
```

Or even better:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "..."))).click()
```

Also:

```
wait(driver, 120).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("iframe_cbk"))
```

Should become:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//...correct xpath selector")))
```

Selenium documentation can be found here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/